# how to update into nested in array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i have a structure like this

```
{

  "name":"xxxxxx",

  "list":[
           {

             "listname":"XXXXX1",
              "card":[
                       {
                         "title":"xxxxxx",
                         "descip":"xxxxxxxxxx",
                         "id":"1213"
                       },
                       {
                         "title":"xxxxxx",
                         "descip":"xxxxxxxxxx",
                         "id":"1214"
                       }

              ] 

           }, 
           {
              "listname":"xxxxxx2",
              "card":[
                       {
                          "title":"xxxxxx",
                          "descip":"xxxxxxxxxx",
                          "id":"1345",
                       },
                       {
                          "title":"xxxxxx",
                          "descip":"xxxxxxxxxx",
                          "id":"1346",
                      }

              ]

           }


   ]

}
```

here listname is unique in list array  and then id is unique in card array.

i want to insert extra two key value pair into specific document of card array . example now i want to add extra key value into id number 1213

the out put should look like this

```
              "card":[
                       {
                          "title":"xxxxxx",
                          "descip":"xxxxxxxxxx",
                          "id":"1213",
                          "name":"XXXXxx",
                           "age":"xxxx"
                       },
                       {
                          "title":"xxxxxx",
                          "descip":"xxxxxxxxxx",
                          "id":"1214",
                      }

                   ]
```

how to update?

Answer (score 0):

Try mongodb [positional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280259/mongodb-use-positional-operator-for-querying) operator.

Your query will be like list.$.id = 123